# PHP Is MySQL DATETIME Field 14 days ago from todays date

Tags: php, mysql

i am trying to write PHP Code that will see if a date in a mysql database (2013-06-05) was 14 days ago or more.

i have selected the records i need using the MySQL SELECT Statement:

```
$sql="SELECT * from table ";
$rs=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());
while($result=mysql_fetch_array($rs))
{
    if(strtotime($result['datetime']) > strtotime('-14 days') )
    {
       echo 'yes';
    }
}
```

but its not displaying what i have echoed. any ideas?

im basically trying to setup an invoice reminder system. i have 3 columns:

```
first_reminder
second_reminder
third_reminder
```

so, 14 days after the `datetime` field it will send an email and put the date the email was sent in the first_reminder field, then 7 days after the first_reminder date it will do the same again and so on...

Comment: Well, apparently `strtotime($result['datetime'])` is never greater than `strtotime('-14 days')` have you echoed either or both of them to check?

Comment: sorry - what do you mean its never greater?

Comment: It seems that your test is never true, i.e. one strtime is never greater than the other.

Comment: ah right okay - so shall i remove the strtotime on the datetime field in the db?

Comment: Doesn't seem like a logic problem, except maybe >=.  You could do this at the query level instead...

Comment: @CharlieFord You need to verify that there are records fulfilling your criteria in your db.

Comment: i cant use it in the query level, i need it to do IF Statements

Comment: Echo the result of `$result['datetime']` and `strtotime($result['datetime'])` for each iteration.  Troubleshoot, debug, and repeat.

Comment: If you do the test at the query level you'll only have the records older than 14 days - no need for an IF at all. FWIW `SELECT * from table` loads the entire table into memory. This is a seriously bad idea.

Comment: i am running multiple IF Statements for all different days so i cannot use queries to run this

Comment: IMHO, it would be better to do this at query time:

`SELECT *, (DATEDIFF(NOW(), datetime) > 14) as is_14_days_ago, (DATEDIFF(NOW(), datetime) > 21) as is_21_days_ago, ... FROM table`

Comment: i have edited my question - hopefully it makes more sense now:)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with MySQL, you'll have to think about the PHP a little differently. To see if something is beyond 14 days in the past.

```
select * from table where some_date < curdate() - interval 14 day
```

To see if it's within the last 14 days.

```
select * from table where some_date > curdate() - interval 14 day
```

Another way to do it would be to pull the actual number of days difference as a calculation (first number subtracts the second number) in the `DATEDIFF` function:

```
select *,DATEDIFF(CURDATE(),date_field) as days from table
```

Then in PHP you could do

```
if ($row['days'] > 14){
  //it's two weeks old
}
```